# Simplify the use of multiple hashings in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, hash

I have a CSV file with about 700 rows and 3 columns, containing `label`, `rgb` and `string` information, e.g.:

```
str;      rgb;                   label;         color
bones;    "['255','255','255']"; 2;             (241,214,145)
Aorta;    "['255','0','0']";     17;            (216,101,79)
VenaCava; "['0','0','255']";     16;            (0,151,206)
```

I'd like to create a simple method to convert one unique input to one unique output.

One solution would be to hash all ROIDisplayColor entries with corresponding label entries as dictionary e.g. `rgb2label`:

```
with open("c:\my_file.csv") as csv_file:
    rgb2label, label2rgb = {}, {} # rgb2str, label2str, str2label...
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
        rgb2label[row[1]] = row[2]
        label2rgb[row[2]] = row[1]
```

This could simply be used as follows:

```
>>> rgb2label[ "['255','255','255']"]
'2'
>>> label2rgb['2']
"['255','255','255']"
```

The application is sumple but requires an unique unique dictionary for every relation (`rgb2label`,`rgb2str`,`str2rgb`,`str2label`, etc...).

**Does a more compact solution with the same ease of use exist?**

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data with headers?

Comment: A hash does not guarantee that `a != b -> hash[a] != hash[b]`, only that `a == b -> hash[a] == hash[b]`.

Comment: @amanb I've added a sample of three rows with headers to the question.

Comment: @chepner thanks for your response. I know, but I happen to know my data is presented this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're limiting yourself to one-to-one dictionaries, so you end up with loads of them (4^2=16 here).

You could instead use one-to-many dictionaries, so you'll have only 4:

```py
for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
    rgb[row[1]] = row
    label[row[2]] = row
```

That you would use like this:

```py
>>> rgb[ "['255','255','255']"][2]
'2'
>>> label['2'][1]
"['255','255','255']"
```

---

You could make this clearer by turning your row into a `dict` as well:

```py
for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
    name, rgb, label, color = row
    d = {"rgb": rgb, "label": label}
    rgb[row[1]] = d
    label[row[2]] = d
```

That you would use like this:

```py
>>> rgb[ "['255','255','255']"]["label"]
'2'
>>> label['2']["rgb"]
"['255','255','255']"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had though about each dict entry being a list, but not of being another dict. Your proposed "dict-of-dicts" would be clearer in use than a "dict-of-list", thanks, I'll consider using it.